# Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc. using database postgres

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, birt

I am working on report using BIRT with postgresql. While I am able to run the report successfully using BIRT viewer, when I try to integrate with tomcat, it gives the below error-

```
Cannot open the connection for the driver: 
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: org.postgresql.Driver.
```

while I have place the oda.jdbc.driver "postgresql-42.2.5" at location "\WEB-INF\lib" but still I'm facing this error.

I am running:

- Birt version:-4.8.0
- postgres version:- postgres9.5 (1.22.2)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It was mistake, I have updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

After viewing error it seems the the JDBC driver jar is on at class path into BIRT runtime so it is not able to load the Driver and throwing error.

Please ensure the Driver jars are placed into libs directory of BIRT runtime installed in your server and it is available into class path at runtime.